# Excel IF ISNA Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to get cell with formula

```
 =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(G2,$S$2:$S$20000,1,FALSE)),U1,"")
```

What i'm trying to get is : I have column with Reference number on G2 and I have a lot of details in column S . I need to find that G2 Value in S column and return B2 cell from row that G2 value was found.

It worked with other data but now i'm combining 2 separate data sheets and I cannot find the problem.

Comment: Instead of `IF(ISNA())` use `IFERROR()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data you are wanting to return from column  `G` is **Left** of your look up column `S`, you will need to use `=Index(Match())` pattern instead of `=Vlookup` (which is limited in that it requires your lookup data to be **Right** of your lookup column).

In your case the following should work:

```
=INDEX(B:B, MATCH(G2,S:S,0), 1)
```

Comment: I've figured one thing Does MATCH formula for example need's to have specifically exact match? Like if G2 = Hello123 , so one of the cells in S column also needs to be Hello123? Because in my column S cells have multiple value , Like name/address/ref and more.

Comment: The last parameter in the `Match()` can be `0` for `less than`, `1` for `Exact Match, or `2` for `greater than`. However, what it sounds like is that you want to match using a wildcard in which case you can probably do something like `Match("*" & G2 & "*", S:S, 0)`.